# How can I custom size of marker icon in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, marker

I use marker in google-map-marker like this

```
<google-map-marker latitude="{{d.lat}}" longitude="{{d.lng}}" title="{{d.name}}" icon="{{d.icon}}">
</google-map-marker>
```

My `{{d.icon}}` is src of image I want to display in google-map. And that's my problem: image was too big but I can't change size of it. How do I change the icon size? I don't see it on the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it with [Computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed).

Add a getIcon method to the icon-attribute.

```
<google-map-marker latitude="{{d.lat}}" longitude="{{d.lng}}" title="{{d.name}}" icon="{{getIcon(d.icon)}}">
</google-map-marker>
```

And add getIcon method inside off your Polymer-script as following:

```
getIcon: function(iconUrl) {
    return new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            iconUrl, //url
            null, //size
            null, //origin
            null, //anchor
            new google.maps.Size(60, 45)
    );
},
```

Hope that helps!